# Searchview - Hide toast that appears by pressing key

Tags: android, toast, searchview

I'm using a filtering SearchView. Everything works fine but, when you leave the keyboard to type and press a button, a kind of toast is shown. Anyone know how to remove it?

[image]

My code is:

```
    searchView = (SearchView) view.findViewById(R.id.buscador_lineas_transporte);
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new OnQueryTextListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            if(TextUtils.isEmpty(newText)){
                lvLineasTransporte.clearTextFilter();
            }
            else{
                lvLineasTransporte.setFilterText(newText);
            }

            return true;
        }
    });
```

Thanks.

### Solved

This keyboard appears when you implement the interface Filterable in your adapater.

Comment: post your complete code ?

Comment: Change the setting of your Softkeyboard in your device.

Comment: Are you sure ?? because when you use whatssap no such problem.

Comment: Change the keyboard :D

Comment: I use swiftkey, i changed for normal keyboard and not work :(

Answer (score 0):

I recommendto use "AutoCompleteTextView" instead of "SearchView".

```
AutoCompleteTextView searchView = (AutoCompleteTextView) view.findViewById(R.id.searchView);
```